# XP's file selector: Is it possible to change the font used in the file name text box (from default system font)?

Tags: windows-xp

Ideally I'd like to change the font (or even just the font size) used in XP's file selector from the standard Microsoft font (MS Sans Serif - I think). It's too small on my monitor and makes adjustments to a file name quite tricky as I strain to see where the cursor actually is!

Alternatively, is it possible to rename another font to replace this font?

The image below demonstrates the font I mean - see the red highlighted boxes:

[image: How to replace system font in the red highlighted boxes?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing, I couldn't find anything back then, but a quick Google search today and I discovered this article which describes how this can sometimes be achieved (and it worked for me):

> [Die Microsoft Sans Serif, Die](http://blog.stealthpuppy.com/windows/die-microsoft-sans-serif-die/).

This article boils down to navigating to the following registry key:

> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes`

and then changing any instances of `MS Sans Serif` to `Segoe UI` (or your chosen font) followed by a reboot.

Comment: Apparently, changing to another font other than `MS Sans Serif` can cause some controls and dialogs to overspill text, but I haven't seen anything obvious so far. The recommendation in this instance is to substitute `Microsoft Sans Serif` (not MS) which apparently is an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

Right click on the desktop to get the Display Properties dialog & select the "Appearance" tab.

You can either just change the Font size on this dialog or select "Advanced" to control both the Font and Size of each component that has text. You'll probably need to experiment to find out which setting (if any) affects the font in the file dialogs.

*I can't upload screen shots from where I'm posting from*

Comment: I've already tried this and unfortunately there's no change with all the different options available in here set to Segoe UI (or any other font for that matter).